# Using Node.js to rename image array based on time

Tags: node.js, image, file-rename

I have a folder of 5 images.

1.jpg,2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg and 5.jpg.

I have a situation where I can only reference one file name. We will call this MainPicture.jpg

Is there a way a could cycle through the folder of images and every 3 hours rename one of the images "MainPicture.jpg"? So that the first three hours "1.jpg" would be renamed "MainPicture.jpg", then after three hours it would rename "2.jpg" to "MainPicture.jpg" and put "1.jpg" back to "1.jpg"? This seems doable but I have no idea where to start. Thanks for any help you could give me with this.

Comment: Welcome, please note that you can search, research when solving a problem. It would be great if you can present some efforts you've tried so far instead of just asking about how to do something. For your problem, it seems [child-process-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise) is useful. You can just run commands that rename the files at a certain interval.

Comment: I've been trying to research for about 2 days, I've been floundering at finding an initial jump off point as I'm still very new to this. This looks exactly like what I would need. I appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction, will certainly be playing with this.

Comment: You would also need a function that would execute every 3 hours. There can be 2 ways to achieve this. The proper way to achieve this will be through a cron job which can be a little complicated to set up. The easier way is to just create a set timeout function that would execute every 3 hours and do your work.

Answer (score 0):

try this module [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

let fileList = fs.readdirSync('./yourImageFolder')
let i = 0

fs.renameSync(`./yourImageFolder/${fileList[i]}`, './yourImageFolder/MainPicture.jpg')
schedule.scheduleJob('* * 0-23/3 * * *', () => {
    fs.renameSync('./yourImageFolder/MainPicture.jpg', `./yourImageFolder/${fileList[i]}`)
    if(i>4){i=0;}else{i++;}
    fs.renameSync(`./yourImageFolder/${fileList[i]}`, './yourImageFolder/MainPicture.jpg')
})
```